# Error: Failed expectation- Expected '3' to equal 3

Tags: jasmine, protractor, typescript-typings

Using jasmine framework in protractor and typescript, getting error in expect statement even the actual and expected are equal, please guide where is the error.

error I am getting

```
Failures:
1) Protractor Demo App should add correctly
  Message:
    Expected '3' to equal 3.
  Stack:
    Error: Failed expectation
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\MyFiles\NewTechonologies\Protractor\TypeScript\Test\calc.ts:27:34)
        at C:\Users\skp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:112:25
        at new ManagedPromise (C:\Users\skp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-we
bdriver\lib\promise.js:1067:7)
        at ControlFlow.promise (C:\Users\skp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-w
ebdriver\lib\promise.js:2396:12)
        at schedulerExecute (C:\Users\skp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\in
dex.js:95:18)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\skp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-we
bdriver\lib\promise.js:2970:14)
```

Here is my spec.ts file

```
import {browser, element, by, By, $, $$, ExpectedConditions} from 'protractor';

import protractor = require('protractor');

describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
  var firstNumber = element(by.model('first'));
  var secondNumber = element(by.model('second'));
  var goButton = element(by.id('gobutton'));
  let value = element(by.xpath("//*[@class='table']/tbody//tr[1]/td[3]"));

  function add(a, b) {
    firstNumber.sendKeys(a);
    secondNumber.sendKeys(b);
    goButton.click();
  }

 beforeEach(function() {
    browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
  });

  it('should add correctly', function() {
    add(1, 2);
    browser.sleep(3000);
    expect<any>(value.getText()).toEqual(3);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[getText()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText) returns a `string`, so your `expect` is failing because they have the same value, but not the same type.

You can either change your assertion to check for the string value:
`expect(value.getText()).toEqual('3');`, or you could return the value from the `getText()` promise and use [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to change the string to a number.